# What is CreateURL in cjuiautocomplete?

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete, yii

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
'name'=>'test1',
'value'=>'test21',
'source'=>$this->createUrl('jui/autocompleteTest'),
// additional javascript options for the autocomplete plugin
'options'=>array(
        'showAnim'=>'fold',
),
));
```

I am new to Yii framework.

i am working on autocomplete but not able to understand the code given above, what does createUrl mean?

do we need to create a page by User or that line itself creates that?

Please help me on this.

Here's the complete Reference code

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
//'model'=>$model,
//'attribute'=>'name',
'id'=>'country-chain',
'name'=>'country_chain',
'source'=>$this->createUrl('request/suggestCountry'),
'options'=>array(
    'delay'=>300,
    'minLength'=>2,
    'showAnim'=>'fold',
    'select'=>"js:function(event, ui) {
        $('#label').val(ui.item.label);
        $('#code').val(ui.item.code);
        $('#call_code').val(ui.item.call_code);
    }"
),
'htmlOptions'=>array(
    'size'=>'40'
),
));
```

Source: [the above code Live Example](http://www.eha.ee/labs/yiiplay/index.php/en/site/widget?view=autocomplete)

What i need to know is where to add model name and where to add Database Field Name

---

my model name is

**detail**
,in this the fields are:

- id , name , email , mobile

i want Name under autocomplete - email and mobile should come like as the above example

Thanks in Advance
Devendar

[image]

Sorry Friend,

Here goes the the structure

Model Name : Details

### controller name is - DetailsController

Under Views > details > _form.php

```
    <div class="form"> <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'details-form',
'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,)); ?>

<p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'id'); ?>


    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'id'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'id'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'name'); ?>
    <?php $this->widget('CAutoComplete',
      array(
                     //name of the html field that will be generated
         'name'=>'name', 
                   //replace controller/action with real ids
         'url'=>array('DetailsController/AutoCompleteLookup'), 
         'max'=>10, //specifies the max number of items to display

                     //specifies the number of chars that must be entered 
                     //before autocomplete initiates a lookup

         ));    ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,'name'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'phone'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'phone'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'phone'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'email'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'email'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'email'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
</div><?php $this->endWidget(); ?> </div><!-- form -->
```

### Controller Code is

```
<?php  class DetailsController extends Controller { /**
 * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2', meaning
 * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
 */
public $layout='//layouts/column2';

/**
 * @return array action filters
 */
public function filters()
{
    return array(
        'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
    );
}

public function actionAutoCompleteLookup()
    {
       if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest && isset($_GET['q']))
       {

          $name = $_GET['q']; 

          $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
          $criteria->condition = "name LIKE :sterm";
          $criteria->params = array(":sterm"=>"%$name%");

          $userArray = User::model()->findAll($criteria);
          $returnVal = '';
          foreach($userArray as $userAccount)
          {
             $returnVal .= $userAccount->getAttribute('name').'|'
                                         .$userAccount->getAttribute('id')."\n";
          }
          echo $returnVal;
       }
    }

/**
 * Specifies the access control rules.
 * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
 * @return array access control rules
 */
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
            'actions'=>array('index','view'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
            'actions'=>array('create','update'),
            'users'=>array('@'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
            'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
            'users'=>array('admin'),
        ),
        array('deny',  // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}

/**
 * Displays a particular model.
 * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
 */
public function actionView($id)
{
    $this->render('view',array(
        'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
    ));
}

/**
 * Creates a new model.
 * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 */
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Details;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Details']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Details'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id1));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}

/**
 * Updates a particular model.
 * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
 */
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Details']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Details'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id1));
    }

    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}

/**
 * Deletes a particular model.
 * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
 * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
 */
public function actionDelete($id)
{
    if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
    {
        // we only allow deletion via POST request
        $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

        // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
        if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
            $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
    }
    else
        throw new CHttpException(400,'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');
}

/**
 * Lists all models.
 */
public function actionIndex()
{
    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Details');
    $this->render('index',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
}

/**
 * Manages all models.
 */
public function actionAdmin()
{
    $model=new Details('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['Details']))
        $model->attributes=$_GET['Details'];

    $this->render('admin',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}

/**
 * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
 * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
 * @param integer the ID of the model to be loaded
 */
public function loadModel($id)
{
    $model=Details::model()->findByPk($id);
    if($model===null)
        throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
    return $model;
}



/**
 * Performs the AJAX validation.
 * @param CModel the model to be validated
 */
protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
{
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='details-form')
    {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }
}
```

}

i tried the above code - mot found any result please help me friend

Thanks
Devendar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this link..

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/25/using-cautocomplete-to-display-one-value-and-submit-another/

implement the code according to this link...autocomplete will work fine..

OR

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
'name'=>'test1',
'value'=>'test21',
'source'=>$this->createUrl('Your Contoller Name / your function Name'),
// additional javascript options for the autocomplete plugin
'options'=>array(
        'showAnim'=>'fold',
),
));
```

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare DetailsController::actionAutoCompleteLookup() in

Comment: i followed the above URL, but its showing error in Controller as Fatel Error Can Not Redeclare

Comment: and what is the controller part for the second option friend

Comment: look first you make model because your autocomplete function fetch the record in the table and show the result.. you place function actionAutoCompleteLookup() in to your contoller

Answer (score 0):

add this to your controller...

```
public function actionAutoCompleteLookup()
        {
           if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest && isset($_GET['q']))
           {

              $name = $_GET['q']; 

              $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
              $criteria->condition = "first_name LIKE :sterm";
              $criteria->params = array(":sterm"=>"%$name%");

              $userArray = User::model()->findAll($criteria);
              $returnVal = '';
              foreach($userArray as $userAccount)
              {
                 $returnVal .= $userAccount->getAttribute('first_name').'|'
                                             .$userAccount->getAttribute('user_id')."\n";
              }
              echo $returnVal;
           }
        }
```

And in the view code like this..

```
<?php $this->widget('CAutoComplete',
          array(
                         //name of the html field that will be generated
             'name'=>'first_name', 
                       //replace controller/action with real ids
             'url'=>array('admin/AutoCompleteLookup'), 
             'max'=>10, //specifies the max number of items to display

                         //specifies the number of chars that must be entered 
                         //before autocomplete initiates a lookup

             ));
    ?>
```

i tried this its work fine...

Comment: Debug Code  : 2012/05/24 13:46:54 [error] [exception.CHttpException.404] exception 'CHttpException' with message 'Unable to resolve the request "DetailsController/AutoCompleteLookup".' in C:\wamp\yii\framework\web\CWebApplication.php:280
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp\yii\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(135): CWebApplication->runController('DetailsControll...')
#1 C:\wamp\yii\framework\base\CApplication.php(162): CWebApplication->processRequest()
#2 C:\wamp\www\myapp\index.php(13): CApplication->run()
#3 {main}